# Exceptions when using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sqlbulkcopy

On several non-related projects, we started experiencing exceptions when using SqlBulkCopy to SQL databases on Azure.

Is anyone else experiencing this behavior as well? I suspect there have been some changes to Azure SQL recently, which broke this BulkCopy.

The error which we encountered is this one:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.WriteUnterminatedValue(Object value, MetaType type, Byte scale, Int32 actualLength, Int32 encodingByteSize, Int32 offset, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Int32 paramSize, Boolean isDataFeed) +6527326
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.WriteValue(Object value, MetaType type, Byte scale, Int32 actualLength, Int32 encodingByteSize, Int32 offset, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Int32 paramSize, Boolean isDataFeed) +105
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.WriteBulkCopyValue(Object value, SqlMetaDataPriv metadata, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isSqlType, Boolean isDataFeed, Boolean isNull) +2117
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.ReadWriteColumnValueAsync(Int32 col) +221
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyColumnsAsync(Int32 col, TaskCompletionSource`1 source) +1529572
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyRowsAsync(Int32 rowsSoFar, Int32 totalRows, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source) +1528377
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinued(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source) +1527301
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source) +1527808
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestContinuedAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source) +1526190
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestAsync(CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source) +1525917
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalAsync(CancellationToken ctoken) +1524291
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32 columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken) +693
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader reader) +386
```

Comment: Hi, I am Satya from MSFT. Is this on V11 or v12? Would you mind sharing your server and database: snarlap at microsoft

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I've mailed you the details. We're seeing these error messages on V12 databases, we don't use V11 for bulk copy.

Comment: A rollback of changes on Azure side has solved the issue.

Comment: Yes, we had a fix world wide deployed ..